# Failure in Installing Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

My computer is unable to install anaconda.
[this is where I got to and it's not operating like it should](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOe2N.png)

Comment: go to their main page by clicking on anaconda banner ....  scroll down and press download ... then install it.

Comment: this is sort of basic, but a youtube video may help you.